# how to self host an existing asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, self-hosting

I am trying to self host an asp.net website / web application
Ideally web forms 
Is this even possible? I have found a fortune of info on how to self host web api, or self host signalR

but I cannot find anything for a simple website (1 page) without all the overhread of iis.

I have tried using nancy, but it doesn't seem like it will run my aspx files, it has its own view engine

Answer (score 0):

I have searched like you but find all about WebApi.
I remember that there is a component of windows called "Internet information services hostable web core".
You can install it by "Turn Windows Features on or off" if you are on a client windows (not on server).
Don't know if you are looking for unit test or other.

I found this page, that i'm going to read. I hope it should be usefull. Mabye if i have time i will update my post after i have made some tries.

Try here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/hostyourownwebserverusingiis7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't self-host web forms using owin, it would require system.web. You'd need to upgrade to asp.net core to be used in the steteless Service Fabric.
Otherwise, I would create a separate SPA app to be hosted in an appservice. Just html, js and css files.